# HIVE Create Table from SubQuery

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

this is my code:

```
create table sw_tmp6_gar_crm as
SELECT * FROM(
  select as_fid_x_gara.dat_fine_perio        as dat_fine_perio,
         as_fid_x_gara.cod_soc               as cod_soc, 
         as_fid_x_gara.cod_kto_gar           as cod_kto_gar, 
         as_fid_x_gara.cod_fido              as cod_fido,
         fid.dat_delib             as dat_delib, 
         fid.dat_scad              as dat_scad  

  from   it_soc_x_fv,
         as_fid_x_gara   ,
         rt_fidi         
  where  it_soc_x_fv.flg_tp_soc     in ('C','N')
    and  as_fid_x_gara.dat_fine_perio   = 2008-03-06
    and  as_fid_x_gara.cod_soc          = it_soc_x_fv.cod_soc
    and  rt_fidi.dat_fine_perio   = as_fid_x_gara.dat_fine_perio
    and  rt_fidi.cod_soc          = as_fid_x_gara.cod_soc       
    and  rt_fidi.cod_fido_tecnico = as_fid_x_gara.cod_fido 
     )         
;
```

I receive the following error:

> error while compiling statement: failed: parseexception line 10:9
>   cannot recognize input near 'it_soc_x_fv' ',' 'as_fid_x_gara' in from
>   source

Can you help me in that?

Comment: Why even have a subquery if you're selecting `*`?

Comment: You have `SELECT * FROM (subquery)` when you can just have `subquery`

Comment: At The beginning I tried as you suggest. I received An error.  Tomorrow I ll try again

Answer (score 1):

You need to give an `alias` name for the sub-query. The below one should work.

```
create table sw_tmp6_gar_crm as
SELECT * FROM(
  select as_fid_x_gara.dat_fine_perio        as dat_fine_perio,
         as_fid_x_gara.cod_soc               as cod_soc, 
         as_fid_x_gara.cod_kto_gar           as cod_kto_gar, 
         as_fid_x_gara.cod_fido              as cod_fido,
         fid.dat_delib             as dat_delib, 
         fid.dat_scad              as dat_scad  

  from   it_soc_x_fv,
         as_fid_x_gara   ,
         rt_fidi         
  where  it_soc_x_fv.flg_tp_soc     in ('C','N')
    and  as_fid_x_gara.dat_fine_perio   = 2008-03-06
    and  as_fid_x_gara.cod_soc          = it_soc_x_fv.cod_soc
    and  rt_fidi.dat_fine_perio   = as_fid_x_gara.dat_fine_perio
    and  rt_fidi.cod_soc          = as_fid_x_gara.cod_soc       
    and  rt_fidi.cod_fido_tecnico = as_fid_x_gara.cod_fido 
     ) tmp         
;
```

But as mentioned in the comments, you don't need a sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't aliased the tables correctly. In your from statement you haven't mentioned any aliases for tables and in your select columns you are saying fid.dat_delib, fid.dat_scad.

But there is no fid table or alias in your query.

As mentioned earlier, there is no need of sub query, you can directly write a query with out sub query.